# An NTFS HDD'e R/W (Read/Write) speed becomes super low on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, mac, external-disk, catalina, ntfs

I have a 1T WD Elements HDD formatted in NTFS that I use between Windows and macOS. On my macOS Catalina I replaced the Finder’s default NTFS driver with ntfs-3g by Tuxera, and I also have NTFS for Mac by Paragon as a fallback utility tool.

Recently I have a huge bunch of videos that I need to export to the HDD with .mp4 format. What I did was I transferred the original files to the HDD, and started exporting straight from the HDD. After a few files have exported a weird thing began to happen: after around 1GB of data has been written onto the disk in 1 task the R/W speed will almost instantly drop significantly. E.g before any R/W copying 1 single 500MB file from the HDD to my Mac takes less than a minute, after R/W 1GB onto the HDD the time to copy the same file will extend to 10mins.

I read that you can use disk utility to run first aid but it’s disabled on my NTFS, I tried first aid on the mother disk but it said there’s nothing wrong. Idk why but my NTFS for Mac doesn’t have the repair/first aid option. I used `sudo dot_clean -m` and some other commands to delete the `._` files, I also manually deleted some of them when plugged to Windows (but I did keep .DS_Store files)

please can someone tell me why might this happen, and how can I fix this, because this disk was labeled R/W speed at 5GB/s, and this speed I’m running at is intolerable.

Comment: You access verify/repair from NTFS for Mac [the App itself] not from Disk Utility. I'm not sure of any consequence of having **both** Tuxera and Paragon, but I wouldn't think it wise.

Comment: How many iops are hitting that drive at idle? (No files open, no finder windows open, eject using disk utility and then mount using disk utility)